# When I make the main page through DirectoryIndex all subdirectories have 403 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When I make the main page through .htaccess DirectoryIndex
as `DirectoryIndex landing/index.php` and the first page of the site became landing/index.php
But all subdirectories have 403 error for example^ /blog doesnt work only if you write: /blog/index.php. I temporary resolved the problem to adding .htaccess file with a row: DirectoryIndex index.php in every subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite as DirectoryIndex landing/index.php index.php
as I understand this row make impact glabally so in catalog "blog" it search landing/index.php and doesnt find it return an error? so now it search "index.php" which exists in directory.